# VBA Code to copy and paste active column with merged cells inside

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy the active column and paste it next to it but the code selects the entire worksheet because it has merged cells in.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Selection
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

Could you please help me adding the missing code to ignore merged cells?

Comment: What does `Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Selection` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is yet another reason to avoid using `Select` in VBA for Excel. Your selection will expand with the merged cells. You can try this:

```
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn
```

And again, you should find some way to avoid counting on the ActiveCell in your code, and use some fully qualified range.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not used to code without Select, need to change to new coding without select

Comment: @Maxwell - See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: @Maxwell The SO Excel-VBA documentation might also help you, e.g. the [best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=201704111544413447144).

Comment: Thanks guys I forgot to ask in mi question. I want to after copying the column, to copy and paste the active column in values

Comment: You mean you want to copy only values without the formats? In that case you can try this: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.value = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.value`

Comment: @A.S.H With this code, the column stays in values but the numbers increase to two decimals. In the other hand when I copy and select paste in values from the Home bar, it keeps the numbers without decimals. Do you know what do I have to add to this line of code to keep the exact format without two decimals? Also the in some cells of the column, it has dates.